Replicate a procedure: generate m dataframes, each one with a variable that includes random values, and append them, in R
Which is the most efficient way to generate m dataframes, where each one has a variable that includes random values, and append them?
Here's an example:
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var = sample(1:500), 10, replace=TRUE)


id var

1  65
2  123
3  42
4  16
5  463
6  129
7  367
8  99
9  489
10 63

If m = 2, two dataframes should be generated and appended, having:
id var
    
 1  65
 2  123
 3  42
 4  16
 5  463
 6  129
 7  367
 8  99
 9  489
 10 63
 1  321
 2  410
 3  78
 4  166
 5  320
 6  478
 7  231
 8  100
 9  105
 10 206


Put the dataframe to be generated in a function
fun <- function() {
  df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var = sample(1:500, 10, replace=TRUE))  
  df
}

Then there are multiple ways to call this function m times and bind.
Base R using replicate
m <- 2
do.call(rbind, replicate(m, fun(), simplify = FALSE))

Base R using lapply
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(m),\(x) fun()))

purrr::map_df
purrr::map_df(seq_len(m), ~fun())


The most efficient way to create a data.frame with those characteristics for an arbitrary m is to avoid appending by creating a single data.frame to begin with:
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var = sample(500, 10*m, 1))

